# Create, configure, and deploy a PHP web app to Azure

Tags: php, git, azure

So recently i have been trying to work on azure. I want to make a php website and connect it to database placed on azure. I am following this tutorial.
**https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-php-get-started/**

I have ran into a problem. Every time i execute this command azure site create --git i get

> Server failed to authenticate your request. Verify that certificate is
>   valid and is associated with this subscription

Comment: I have a Microsoft Dream Spark subscription.

Comment: 1: No need to add explicit (and bold) calls for help (kinda what StackOverflow is for). 2: Subscription type is irrelevant. 3: The error is related to your command-line call using `azure` - related to you needing to login first. Did you try to authenticate before creating your site? 4: If you're struggling with the command line, have you attempted to get things working via the portal?

Comment: I have created a webapp through portal but i don't know how to develop the website once the webapp is deployed. I am new to azure.

Comment: Never mind i tried it through portal it worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: If you solved your issue, you should either delete the question or post (and accept) the answer, to properly close this.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps to deploy PHP project on Azure Web Apps Server by git:

- 1, Sign in [Azure manage portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) , Click “NEW” in bottom, select “COMPUTE”=>”WEB APP”=>”QUICK CREATE” and enter server name in URL section, to create a new empty Web application.
  [image]
- 2, Click “WEB APP” button on the left navigation, in this dashboard we can see the web site we created above, click web site name to enter in management page.

[image]

- 3, In dashboard page, click “set up deployment form source control” in “quick glance” column, select “Local Git repository” to create a git repository. Now in deployments page, we can see the guide to deploy project by git.
- 4, In your local project root directory, run the following commands to deploy as shown on the page:

[image]

Furthermore, we can simply use FTP tool to upload the project to Azure Server, please see this simple sample:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sams_blog/archive/2014/11/14/azure-websites-deploy-php-website-using-ftp.aspx